# Tag Recognition with Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, object-recognition, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Today, it is still very challenging to do object recognition in real time while the robot and the object are both moving. Hence, I am thinking of putting some special red/green tags on the target objects or labels. Do you think it will make things better or worse? Also, which ROS package is the most suitable for recognizing the tags? I would like to implement this in TurtleBot with Kinect. Thank you very much for your suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58398/tag-recognition-with-kinect/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ar markers are the best to detect probably, use the [ar_kinect](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_kinect) package

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-18**:
So it is okay even if things are moving?

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-03-18**:
I my research the markers are static and the camera is moving, that works. The system is reasonably robust but you should try it in your own application.